# created splash screen with background image and the next activity, if i run the project splash screen appears without displaying image

Tags: android

i created splash screen with background image and the next activity, if i run the project splash screen appears without displaying image and progress bar and does not show the next activity, please help me to recover this prob.
my splash screen xml code is this

enter code here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:context=".SplashScreenActivity" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my manifest file is this

```
enter code here <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your manifest file.

Comment: "with background image and the next activity" what does this mean?

Comment: two activities, one is splash screen and next activity is mainActivity

Comment: Does the app crash? Is there any exception? If yes, please post logcat message

Comment: no it doesnt crash, only the splash screen appears it does not navigate to the next activity

Comment: Have you written the startActivity (new Intent (this, NextActivity.class)) properly in your SplashActivity.java after your splash screen time is up?

Comment: yes i had given, like this  @Override
         public void run()
         {

             super.run();

             try
             {
                 Thread.sleep(500);

                     Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                     finish();

             }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                 Log.v("log",e.toString());
             }   
         }//End Run

     }

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your problem is your layout. You're trying to use a RelativeLayout to accomplish having a progressbar show up on top of all the other content. Instead you need to use something like a FrameLayout to accomplish this. That will allow you stack the views one on top of the other. Then when you don't need the indication of progress anymore, you can set the progressbar to invisible or gone.

If you look @ your xml, you'll see you have the textview and the imageview both set to be centered in the relativelayout. That's not gonna work. A RelativeLayout is for positioning things relative to each other (or the parent) and you can't just stick two children in the same spot.